# Integration test failing for footer links

Tags: railstutorial.org

I am refreshing my knowledge of RoR for a forthcoming project and working through the Rails Tutorial, and have competed up to section [5.3.4 "Layout link tests"](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-layout_link_tests) without any major problems.

This section has got me stumped, as far as I can tell, my code has been changed to match the tutorial so should be working.

The integration tests for the header are working fine, but neither of the footer integration tests are working.

The links on the pages are working as expected, but the test is returning (and if the About test is commented the same error is occurring for the Contact test).

I am missing something really obvious, but I can't identify it.

My code is in my [Bitbucket Repository](https://bitbucket.org/neil_sgp/blue-titanium-corbeau/branch/Failing-5-3-4)

```
 FAIL["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 1.4785866689999239]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (1.48s)
        Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/about"]", found 0..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

The links are present in the page html

```
<nav>
  <ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

site_layout_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App</title>
    <%= render 'layouts/rails_default' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

_footer.html.erb

```
<footer class="footer">
  <small>
    The <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> by
    <a href="http://www.michaelartl.com/">Michael Hartl</a>
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
      <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Thanks for taking time to look at the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `home.html.erb`. Your last line closes the page: `</html>`. So when you use that in `application.html.erb`, the page ends before your footer is created.

That said...for some reason, that's not how the page actually renders in a browser. It's as if the extra closing tag is ignored. So your footer actually displays.

Comment: Thank you, the superfluous `</html>` in home was the problem.

Comment: Thinking about it, I suspect that browsers are slightly more tolerant of formatting issues than the test code. This is a good thing (although it did have me flummoxed!)

Comment: @NeilStoker - I was surprised by this as well. I guess it makes sense that browsers would cover for obvious errors, but it certainly made finding that bug tricky!